# TSQL - What is the fastest way to check for more than one record?

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

Sometimes I need to check if *at least one record* is present, usually I use a:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM [SomeTable] WHERE [Fields] = [Values]) BEGIN
-- action
END
```

Is there a fast way to check if *more than one* record is present? I could do something like:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [SomeTable] 
                        WHERE [Fields] = [Values] 
                                HAVING Count(*) > 1) 
BEGIN
    -- action
END
```

But I'm not sure if it is the fastest way of doing this as it will test all the records in the set. Is there a faster way?

The 'where' part can be quite complex and could consist of multiple ANDs and ORs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SQL Server does not generally short circuit aggregate queries. Sometimes it can transform a `HAVING COUNT(*) > 0` query to use the same plan as `EXISTS` ([discussed in the comments here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andrew_kelly/archive/2007/12/15/exists-vs-count-the-battle-never-ends.aspx)) but that's as far as it goes.

A `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`  query will always count all rows even though in theory it could stop counting after row no 2.

With that in mind I would use

```
IF EXISTS(
  SELECT * FROM (
                 SELECT TOP 2 *
                 FROM [SomeTable] 
                 WHERE [Fields] = [Values] 
) T
HAVING COUNT(*)=2)
```

The `TOP 2` iterator will stop requesting rows after the second one is returned and thus allow the inner query to shortcircuit early rather than returning them all and counting them.

Example plans for both versions are below

[image: Plans]

Regarding the question in the comments about

> "How can you tell which one is best? Is it the query cost?"

In the particular case shown in the plans above cost would be a reasonable indication as the estimated and actual row counts are quite accurate and the two plans are very similar except for the addition of the `TOP` iterator. So the additional cost shown in the plan is entirely a representation of the fact that additional number of rows need to be scanned (and possibly read in from disc) and counted.

It is quite clear cut in this case that this just represents additional work. In other plans it may not be. The addition of the `TOP 2` may change the query tree underneath it significantly (e.g. disfavouring plans with [blocking iterators](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2006/06/19/637048.aspx))

In that case the cost shown in execution plans may not a reliable metric. Even in actual execution plans the cost shown is based on estimates so is only as good as those are and even if the estimated row counts are good the costs shown are still just based on certain modelling assumptions.

SQL Kiwi puts it well in [this recent answer on the DBA site](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/29650)

> optimizer cost estimates are mainly only useful for internal server
>   purposes. They are not intended to be used to assess potential
>   performance, even at a 'high level'. The model is an abstraction that
>   happens to work reasonably well for the internal purposes it was
>   designed for. The chances that estimated costs bear any sensible
>   resemblance to real execution costs on your hardware and configuration
>   is very small indeed.
>
> Choose other metrics to compare performance, based on whatever real
>   issues are important to you.

logical reads (shown when `SET STATISTICS IO ON;`) are one such metric that can be looked at but again focusing on this exclusively can be misleading. Testing query duration is probably the only reliable way but even that is not an exact science as performance can vary dependent upon concurrent activity on the server (waits for memory grants, DOP available, number of relevant pages in the cache).

In the end it just comes down to getting a query plan that looks to be an efficient use of the resources on your server.

Comment: Would `SELECT TOP 2 1` optimize it further?

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker - No. Taking the following query as an example `IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 2 * FROM master..spt_values WHERE high=2) T HAVING COUNT(*)=2) PRINT 'Y'` If you look at the execution plan you will see that in fact no columns at all are returned in the output list from the clustered index scan. SQL Server sees that it just needs to count the rows so it doesn't pass around the whole row. The plan whether you use `*` , `1`, `1/0` will be the same.

Comment: How can you tell which one is best? Is it the query cost? I've noticed that query cost of the two versions seems to be the same if you use an indexed column in the where clause.

Comment: @axrwkr Expanded my answer a bit. RE: benefit of sort circuiting if you haven't many rows in the first place that would match then stopping the scan after the 2nd won't give that much benefit! This query demonstrates that it can equally apply on indexed columns. `SET STATISTICS IO ON;CREATE TABLE #T(X INT, Filler CHAR(8000) NULL); CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX ON #T(X); INSERT INTO #T (X) SELECT 1 FROM master..spt_values; IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 2 * FROM #T WHERE X = 1 ) T HAVING COUNT(*)=2) PRINT 'Y';IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM #T WHERE X = 1 HAVING COUNT(*)>1) PRINT 'Y';DROP TABLE #T`

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there are tricks that'll enable you to perform this check faster - although it'll depend very much upon your schema (especially indexes), and a particular check may work for one situation and not for another.

Something like the below might work for you.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [SomeTable] T1
           INNER JOIN [SomeTable] T2
           ON T1.UniqueID <> T2.UniqueID
           WHERE T1.[Fields] = T1.[Values]
           AND T2.[Fields] = T2.[Values]) 
BEGIN
    -- action
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother with `top` or `select 1`.

```
if exists (select * ...)
```

is just as fast.

Comment: Can you back it up? (I'm seeing it everywhere, which in itself doesn't proof anything.) Is the second statement as fast as it goes? My where can be quite complex.

Comment: This is correct for `EXISTS` but doesn't answer the main point of the question which is about short circuiting if `>1` matching row exists.

Comment: @Kees, you can compare your actual execution plans.

Comment: using select * is bad news, better to name the field rather than rely on sql to goto the system tables to look up the number of fields

Comment: "select 1" is usually used instead of "select *" or "select <column>" to make it clear right in the SQL that you don't really care about the values in this case. This is intended more as a help for the next maintainer than the database.

Answer (score 1):

I got excellent performance with this solution in a table with 19 million records:

```
IF EXISTS (
        SELECT '1' FROM (
            SELECT TOP(2) '1' AS 'N'
            FROM TBL_KV3) AS Z
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1     
            ) 
    SELECT '1'
ELSE
    SELECT '0'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the performance, but you could use a `CTE` and `COUNT(*)OVER`:

```
WITH Match AS
(
    SELECT t1.*, COUNT(*)OVER(PARTITION BY t1.Fields)AS CountFields
    FROM SomeTable t1
    WHERE t1.Fields=@Values
)
SELECT m1.* 
FROM Match m1
WHERE CountFields >= 2
```

[**Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f011c/2/0)